# Replacing text in Text Files

Tags: excel, vba, file, text, ms-word

I created a text file that contains different sections. I need to pull the information at a later time.

I split each line of the txt file to have each variable.

Example:

```
[Title]The Maps[TitleEnd]  
[Name]Smith,John[NameEnd]  
[Subject]Mythical Creatures[SubjectEnd]  
[Text]Today i learned about this information and blah blah blah[TextEnd]  
etc.
```

I need to open the txt file, find the correct brackets i.e. [Text] to [TextEnd] then replace it.

Example:

```
[Text]Today i learned about this information and blah blah blah[TextEnd]
```

to

```
[Text]Today i learned about this information and  i learned more things and blah blah blah[TextEnd]
```

I looked at a couple of examples. One has gotten me close but instead of replacing 1 line, it puts everything on 1 line.

```vb
Private Sub SavePro_Click()

    IRBNum = ThisDocument.IRBNetID
    FilePath = "Abstract.txt"
    TextFile = FreeFile
    Open FilePath For Input As #1
    StrFinal = "[Text]*"
    While EOF(1) = False
        Line Input #1, strline
        StrFinal = StrFinal + ModifyText(strline)
    Wend
    StrFinal = Left(StrFinal, Len(StrFinal) - 2)
    Close 1
    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    Print #1, StrFinal
    Close #1

End Sub

Function ModifyText(ByVal strInput As String) As String
    Dim arrString() As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    arrString = Split(strInput, " ")
    strOutput = arrString(0) + " " + SubText.Text
    ModifyText = strOutput
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an XML format

```vb
<xml>
 <Title>The Maps</Title>
 <Name>Smith,John</Name>
 <Subject>Mythical Creatures</Subject>
 <Text>Today i learned about this information and blah blah blah</Text>
</xml>
```

most of the code has been written for you.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub update()

    Dim xDoc, oNode
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xDoc.Load Path & "\Abstract.xml"
    
    Set oNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("xml/Text")
    MsgBox "Text: " & oNode.nodeTypedValue
    oNode.nodeTypedValue = "Today i learned about this information " & vbCrLf & _
           "and  i learned more things and blah blah blah"
       
    xDoc.Save Path & "\Abstract.xml"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this has worked pretty well for me until i start trying to use it with another file i have created the only thing i have changed is the file name from Abstract.xml to Checklist.xml and no it will not find the path. anyone have idea why?

Comment: @amongtheshadows Remove the Path & and try with full path to file like "C:\folder\subfolder\Checklist.xml"

Comment: I tried that as well and got the same result.  but i did notice after i set up the files in the same way the one that works has everything one tab over after <xml> and the one that fails still has everything in line.  but they set up the exact same way

Comment: i am setting up this way:
Dim xDoc as string
FilePath = "C:\My Documents\Books\"
FileName = "Abstract.xml"
xDoc = FilePath & FileName
Open xDoc For Output As #1
Print #1, "<xml>"
Print #1, "<Text>"
Close #1

(same thing again for Checklist.xml)
Thank you for helping

Comment: @amongthe I don't understand what you are doing, my code doesn't have the line Open xDoc For Output As #1 ? Are you trying to create a new file if so you need to close the tags with Print #1, "</Text>" & vbCrLf & "</xml>" .

Comment: yes that is the way i am creating the file at first, then when i save the changes i do the one you created.

Comment: @amongthe Create a blank template with just tags using notepad++. Use my code to open it, enter the data, and then save with a different name leaving the template unchanged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228802/discussion-between-amongtheshadows-and-cdp1802).